# How to prevent users from deleting a liferay portlet?

Tags: liferay

I have an IFrame portlet in a liferay page. 
I want some quick fix to prevent logged in users from deleting that portlet. It can be done via user roles, css, code, or whatever. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest modifying your themes `portlet.vm` template.
It's pretty straight forward, if you take a quick look at the sevencogs theme:

```
#if ($portlet_display.isShowBackIcon())
    <a href="$portlet_back_url" class="portlet-icon-back">#language ("return-to-full-page")</a>
#else
    $theme.iconOptions()
    $theme.iconMinimize()
    $theme.iconMaximize()
    $theme.iconClose()
#end
```

Just remove `$theme.iconClose()` and your users won't be able to close/remove portlets anymore.
Note that this applies to **all** portlets (since its a template).

If you'd like to deactivate the close button for some portlets only, I would simply do it by CSS. Do a `display: none` on the class `.portlet-close-icon` which is inherited by the div holding the iFrame.
In particular

```
.portlet-iframe .portlet-close-icon {
     display: none;
}
```

will do the job for the liferay iFrame portlet.

Answer (score 4):

You always can do that:

```
    $theme.iconMinimize()
    $theme.iconMaximize()               
#if ($permissionChecker.isOmniadmin())
    $theme.iconClose()
#end
```