# How to handle permissionChecker in freemarker template liferay

Tags: permissions, liferay, freemarker

In this page guys described [How to prevent users from deleting a liferay portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290486/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-a-liferay-portlet) in velocity template.
Now I have question: How to deal with it in freemarker template?

Comment: Its as same as in case of freemarker template. You can see list of context attributes available in free-marker in FreeMarkerVariablesImpl.java